# cin not reading full strings

Tags: c++, string, input

I am working through the exercises in the book Accelerated C++ and I am having a problem with reading strings within a while loop. The code seems to be somewhat selective in how much of the person's name it reads. Any ideas why this is being cut off? I've gone into Xcode to debug it and it seems that the full name just isn't being read in.

The idea of the code is that you can type a student's name followed by a midterm grade, a final exam grade and then a series of homework grades to calculate their final mark. It will then return the names in alphabetical order with the final mark next to it, formatted so the final marks are in a single column.

`GradeFinder.ccp` (the main)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "grade.cpp"


using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::domain_error;
using std::max;
using std::setprecision;
using std::sort;
using std::streamsize;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    vector<Student_info> students;
    Student_info record;
    string::size_type maxlen=0;

    while (read(cin,record))
    {
    maxlen=max(maxlen,record.name.size());
    students.push_back(record);
    }

    sort(students.begin(),students.end(),compare);

    for (vector<Student_info>::size_type i=0; i!=students.size();++i)
    {
    cout<<students[i].name
        <<string(maxlen+1-students[i].name.size(),' ');

        try
        {
        double final_grade=grade(students[i]);
        streamsize prec=cout.precision();
        cout<<setprecision(3)<<final_grade
            <<setprecision(prec);
            }
        catch (domain_error e)
        {
            cout<<e.what();
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

'Student_info.h'

```
#ifndef GUARD_Student_info
#define GUARD_Student_info

// Student_info.h header file
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Student_info {
    std::string name;
    double midterm, final;
    std::vector<double> homework;
};

bool compare(const Student_info&, const Student_info&);
std::istream& read(std::istream&, Student_info&);
std::istream& read_hw(std::istream&, std::vector<double>&);

#endif // GUARD_Student_info
```

`Student_info.cpp` (reads the command line input of the names and relevant marks)

```
#include "Student_info.h"

using std::istream;
using std::vector;

bool compare(const Student_info& x, const Student_info& y)
{
    return x.name<y.name;
}

istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s)
{
    is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.exam;
    read_hw(is,s.homework);
    return is;
}

istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
{
    if (in)
    {
        hw.clear();

        double x;
        while (in>>x)
        hw.push_back(x);    
    in.clear();

    }
    return in;
}
```

The following is an example of the command line input, interestingly the name Penelope causes problems when it isn't the first name entered and Johnny is always fine.

```
Chapter4 Alex$ ./GradeFinder 
Johnny 90 90 90 90 90
Frederick 80 80 80 80 80
Penelope 85 85 85 85 85
Polly 95 95 95 95 95 95
Johnny   90
lope     85
olly     95
rederick 80

Chapter4 Alex$ ./GradeFinder 
Penelope 85 85 85 85 85 
Frederick 80 80 80 80 80 80
Polly 95 95 95 95 95 95
Johnny 90 90 90 90 90 90
Johnny    90
Penelope  85
olly      95
rederick  80
```

Comment: You are using `std::istream::operator>>` for all of your reading. `operator>>` ignores line breaks and stops reading a string when it encounters whitespace. Also, on the few lines that don't contain any exam or homework scores, your reading will fail. So you are not always reading what you are expecting.  Consider using `std::getline()` first to read an entire line of text into a `std::string` and then use `std::istreamstream` to read individual values from that line as needed.

Comment: Edited to include student_info.h, a necessary file in understanding program behavior. The full source is here: https://github.com/acarabott/accelerated-cplusplus/tree/master/04

Comment: Please consider editing your question to contain only a [mcve] ...it seems like there are only 2 functions actually reading from the istream, so you could clearly reduce the number of code we have to read.

Comment: I can see why getline would eliminate my issue. However, I was hoping someone would be able to explain why Penelope has 4 letters ignored whilst the others only have 1 and Johnny always seems to appear in full.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is that using `libc++` seems to swallow certain characters (a,b,c,d,e,f,i,n,p,x) when they occur at the start of the name.

By switching the compile to `libstdc++` it no longer removes characters from the names. However, I'm not sure how to fix this problem whilst still using `libc++`.

See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2addyw/c_strange_behaviour_when_attempting_to_read_a/) for the answers for an identical problem. It seems it might be a Mac related issue.